# ASP .NET Core Identity external login from mobile native application

Tags: asp.net, facebook, identityserver4, identity

I have a Asp.net Core Website, It's using Facebook login (external login) with support of Asp.net Core Identity.

By using Web Browser, after Facebook login success, The facebook website redirect to Asp.net Core Identity endpoint at mywebsite.com/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?handler=Callback to issuse cookie or JWT token...

As below picture. The GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() will receive Facebook response and return user data to the info variable.

[image]

My problem is:

I'm making a android native app. It's also allow using Facebook to login. But, it's Facebook Native installed on Android phone, after Facebook login success, it return access_token, user id to my native app (not send response to mywebsite.com/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?handler=Callback).

I have tried to manually send Facebook login response from my native app to the endpoint, but GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()  return null.

I think Because It didn't called from Facebook, so it return null.

What should I do to make GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()  return user infomation by data from my native app

Comment: same issue here!! ever get to the bottom of this??

Answer (score 0):

I think you should register a deep link in native app and then add the link in facebook in client you registered  as another urlredirect.